# Different answers on python and .net for encrypting with a single public key

Tags: c#, python, .net, encryption

I have this code in .net:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider cipher = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
cipher.FromXmlString(publicKey);
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
byte[] cipherText = cipher.Encrypt(data, false);
result = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
```

and this code in python:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64encode
key = open(public_key_loc, "r").read()
rsakey = RSA.importKey(key)
encrypted_data = rsakey.encrypt(input, 32)[0]
result = b64encode(encrypted_data)
```

When I run this codes with a public key, I get different answers on the same input!

I've searched and found out that both `Crypto (python)` and `RSACryptoServiceProvider (.net)` are using the `RSA` algorithm.

**EDIT:**
The public key used in `.net` is created by removing `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` from the key and converting it to XML.

**Example:**

**PublicKey:**

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCETtzC9pZ+dnQ0z0pXL6pNrkn4vGdbLTf3fhH5
MsVYsFIPuuaUSC9EnbTa8G9p1AIKNsjQaBbzfkvgdu5Tz8qEXZfYQV2bnSCtl/87M7Xn0raAmGTr
jSliTdsxMyJHObzAPkamjHemAxHd9VkwXfZOPAh00ueag+buTAkbzL1MlQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**Input:**

```
"6000306"
```

**.net output:**        `SpDXp/KCea8DlIuhow6k8+uyfGFe93r9+w39ROoSRAggF9dBU3boK5zRareOQo2//7LyMZZVVklvDCFPo/irJtgbxjn6c0C7gHrL7ubKRG7iVaa9iSF1u13gdRZvLGy/MKOxiz9G+FKLZfJYtkiOSLkJHXXMWTGSNedQsdraJZc=`

**Python output:**
    `Q3H0NTJYZzymWhWDtMCSzcqZ0D/Nvumq3VqvFCvQRlib82pth48DbVcKwjrmSjT0F/ipi7mnSq8M7BLX/7wo4tQFqul9+avyI/eAW5LKbuFZiiD8eP0GMwEZZyHGurFKhxu+1Qa0dftCIeiIMVJsVaHcUD254BSkYQC04Fflvfc=`

What is the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: what kind of RSA? to my knowledge there are multiple variations of this asymmetric encryption algorithm

Comment: 'similar' input is not *exactly the same input*.

Comment: We'll need to see sample inputs and outputs to be able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I Edited and added sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: RSA encryption (PKCS 1 or OAEP) is not stable, rerunning either python or C# should give a different answer than last time. (PKCS 1 signatures are stable, PSS are not)

Comment: No the codes always return this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the python code, you have neglected to use the PKCS1_v1_5 module you imported. As a result, you're getting plain vanilla RSA encryption with no padding. This is not what you want. If instead your code is:

```
key = open(public_key_loc, "r").read()
rsakey = RSA.importKey(key)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(input)
result = b64encode(encrypted_data)
```

Then you'll see that the cipher changes every time, even with the same input, just like the C# side does. PKCS1 version 1.5 type 2 padding includes a random component, so the output should never be the same.

The PKCS1_OAEP module is the more modern choice, and is supported by .NET simply by change the `false` to `true` in the `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt()` method.